# Generator of combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, combinations, code-generation

I want to write a code which gives me all the possible combinations of n elements in a k length k>n.The issue with this code is that i run out of memory quite fast.I was wondering if someone knew how to fix this with generators.I don't want to get all the possible combinations of a list elements. I want to get all the combinations of the elements in a certain length.
Thanks.

```
def allstrings(alphabet, length):
    """Find the list of all strings of 'alphabet' of length 'length'"""

    if length == 0: return []

    c = [[a] for a in alphabet[:]]
    if length == 1: return c

    c = [[x,y] for x in alphabet for y in alphabet]
    if length == 2: return c

    for l in range(2, length):
        c = [[x]+y for x in alphabet for y in c]

    return c

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for p in allstrings(['a','b','c'],4):
        print (p)
```

Comment: Have you looked in [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)? I'm assuming you're doing this as a learning exercise, not because you actually need all the combinations of those three letters—but notice that `combinations`, `product`, etc. all come with "roughly equivalent" code that you can read to see how to do it yourself.

Comment: It was an example, i need the combinations of 64 elements in a length of 10000 approximately but i get Memoryerror. Thanks anyway!

Comment: "i need the combinations of 64 elements in a length of 10000" - no you don't, you need to figure out a better way to solve whatever problem you wanted to use that output for. You're never going to finish going through all that output even if you dodge the memory problems.

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools

itertools.combinations('alphabet', length)
```

From [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)